# Why does Alpine-based sshd shut down when first session ends?

Tags: ssh, docker, pam, alpine

I have a simple Docker container for a [purposeful](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) `sshd` server whose image derives from `alpine:latest`. It currently uses `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -e -ddd` as its entrypoint. When I `ssh` into it for running a certain command remotely, that command executes alright, but then `sshd` and hence the container immediately shut down.

[Elsewhere](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) there is a recommendation titled "SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login" in terms of enabling `session optional pam_loginuid.so` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. This sounds promising, but Alpine's `sshd` (from `apk add openssh`) apparently comes without PAM, plus I am not sure how this would function.

Can somebody please enlighten me as to how `sshd` inside an Alpine-based container can be made to persist across many SSH sessions in order to support normal operation?

**UPDATE** Here are the last few lines of `sshd`'s log output before it shuts down:

```
Received disconnect from 1.2.3.4 port 29213:11: disconnected by user
Disconnected from user rts 1.2.3.4 port 29213
debug1: do_cleanup
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
```

Comment: Why is it shutting down? Did you actually go and check the logs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Of course I checked the logs. They are apparently silent about a specific reason. I'll add the last few lines to my question. Is there anything special to look out for in them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because of the -d flag. From the sshd's [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd):

**-d**' Debug mode. The server sends verbose debug output to the system log, and does not put itself in the background. **The server also will not fork and will only process one connection**. This option is only intended for debugging for the server. Multiple -d options increase the debugging level. Maximum is 3.

Comment: Good catch, the part here in bold had escaped my attention.